# how to add break line in JSON data file

Tags: json, visual-studio, format, line-breaks

How do I add a break line between each 'step' in my JSON data file in visual studio code?

Below is an example image of how the text is displayed on chrome. below the image is the example code [image]

"Method": [
    " 1.Place all the ingredients in a bowl and add 250ml cold water. Mix together with a spoon until you have a spongy mixture, cover with cling film and leave at room temperature overnight",
    " 2.Tip the dough onto a floured surface and gently shape into a round. Dust a piece of baking parchment heavily with flour and sit the dough on top. Cover with a tea towel and leave to prove for 1 hr until doubled in size",
    " 3.Heat oven to 220C/200C fan/gas 7. Place a flat baking tray on the middle shelf of the oven. Dust the dough with flour and slash with a utility knife.",
    " 4.Bake for 25-30 mins until the loaf sounds hollow when tapped on the bottom. Leave the bread to cool completely."
    ]

Comment: JSON is data format, it does not know about how the data will be shown eventually (that's the job of view if your JSON data is treated as model). May be in view, you can slice the long text into separate lines based on some delimter (like step-id in your case) and show it as bulletted list

Answer (score 0):

If is not related to a particular code, you can select a comma "," and use the shortcut

```
SHIFT+CTRL+L
```

to select all the commas. Press the "RIGHT ARROW" to move right after all the commas and lose the selection (to avoid the cancellation of them) and then press "Enter".